# C++ Trying to iterate through a map of a constant class?

Tags: c++, dictionary, iterator

I have the following code to override the << operator
So far, I have located the error to be ++it. My program crashes (SIGTERM) whenever it comes to this piece of code.

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Kooi& kooi) {
    map<int, Dier*>::const_iterator it;
    for (it = kooi.de_dieren->begin(); it != kooi.de_dieren->end(); ++it) {
        os << it->second << endl;
    }
}

return os;
```

EDIT: Full header file of the Kooi class:

```
#ifndef kooi_H
#define kooi_H 1.3


#include <string>   // voor: std::string
#include <iostream> // voor: std::ostream
#include <map>      // voor: std::map<K,V>
#include <iterator> // voor: next
#include "Dier.h"   // voor: class Dier


/** @class Kooi Kooi.h
 * A cage class to hold animals of the same type.
 */
class Kooi
{
        // The Kooi output operator to print the cage.
        // It also prints any animals within.
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Kooi&);

    private:
        std::string      de_diersoort;  // the animal category
        std::map<int, Dier*>    *de_dieren;     // the animal container

    public:
        /// Construct a cage for the given type of animals
        /// @param diersoort    The animal category
        ///     @pre diersoort must be a non-empty string
        Kooi(const std::string& diersoort);

        /// Destroy a cage, any animals within should also be destroyed
        ~Kooi();

        /// Return the animal category of this cage
        /// @return The animal category
        inline const std::string&  getSoort() const {
            return de_diersoort;
        }

        /// Add an animal to this cage
        /// @param  nummer   The unique number of the animal
        ///     @pre That animal number may not already exist in this cage
        /// @param  dier     The animal to be added
        ///     @pre The type of that animal must match with the type of this cage
        void     addDier(int nummer, Dier *dier);

        /// Lookup an animal in this cage
        /// @param  nummer  The number of the animal sought
        ///     @pre That animal number must be >= 0
        /// @returns 0 when the animal is not in this cage
        Dier    *getDier(int nummer) const;

        /// Remove an animal from this cage
        /// @param  nummer  The number of the animal to be removed
        ///     @pre That animal number must exist in this cage
        void     erase(int nummer);

        /// Tell the number of animals in this cage
        ///  (used e.g.to calculate the salary of a animalkeeper)
        inline int      size() const {
            return de_dieren->size();
        }

        // =====================================
        /// Save this cage (and the animals) in a file
        void saveFile(std::ostream& out) const;
};


/// Kooi output operator (prints both the cage and all animals within)
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Kooi& kooi);


#endif  /*kooi*/

// vim:sw=4:ai:aw:ts=4:
```

Also, I'm 100% positive the program crashes at `++it` for some reason.

**Please note this code is part of a school assignment so we're not supposed to mess with the code too much. The scope of this assignment is just the kooi.cc file**

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the posted code. Is `de_dieren` pointing to a valid map? Of course, unless you're doing something strange, it shouldn't be a pointer at all.

Comment: Most probably you have garbage in your pointer `de_dieren`. Do you follow "rule of 5" ? Post MCVE if you want a real help

Comment: Please post the `Kooi` class definition, including constructors and operators. Show how you create, destroy, and populate the map. Please also add the backtrace and highlight which line is being executed at the time of the crash in your code. Please also tell us what type of a crash you got (SIGSEGV, SIGFPE, whatever).

Comment: Get some hints here for improving this question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve - and some hints here on improving your code: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/163279